# How do I zip files that don't match certain criteria?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, zip

I need to make a zip archive with all files in a directory that don't have ".processed" in their names. I came up with this line

```
cd source_directory && find . -type f \( ! -iname "*.processed" \) -print | zip target_direcory/result_test.zip -@
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do the file names end by `.processed`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: @Bobby: What errors are you actually seeing?

Comment: @Allan: OP's attempt of using `\( ! -iname "*.processed" \) -print` will work just fine, no need to use `-not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following command and it will work:

```
cd source_directory && find . -type f -not -iname '*.processed' | zip target_direcory/result_test.zip -@
```

to negate a condition use `-not` with find and **always always always** use **simple quotes** in the file name with find to avoid your shell to interpret special characters.

**TEST:**

```
$ tree .
.
├── a
├── a.processed
├── b
└── c

0 directories, 4 files

$ find . -type f -not -iname '*.processed' | zip output.zip -@
  adding: c (stored 0%)
  adding: a (stored 0%)
  adding: b (stored 0%)

$ tree
.
├── a
├── a.processed
├── b
├── c
└── output.zip

$ less output.zip
Archive:  output.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2018-03-07 16:44 00000000  c
       3  Stored        3   0% 2018-03-07 16:45 ed6f7a7a  a
       4  Stored        4   0% 2018-03-07 16:45 3aa2d60f  b
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       7                7   0%                            3 files
```

Comment: Yep. This works, but I found out that my code also works if I execute it manually. Some issues with my script, I guess. Thank you for your help, it is a good explanation, I suppose, many people may find this useful

Answer (score 1):

My manual says (and it is almost the same under Linux):

```
   -x files
   --exclude files
          Explicitly exclude the specified files, as in:

                 zip -r foo foo -x \*.o

          which will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while  exclud-
          ing  all  the  files  that  end in .o.  The backslash avoids the
          shell filename substitution, so that the name matching  is  per-
          formed by zip at all directory levels.

          Also possible:

                 zip -r foo foo -x@exclude.lst

          which  will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while exclud-
          ing  all  the  files  that  match  the  patterns  in  the   file
          exclude.lst.

          The long option forms of the above are

                 zip -r foo foo --exclude \*.o

          and

                 zip -r foo foo --exclude @exclude.lst

          Multiple patterns can be specified, as in:

                 zip -r foo foo -x \*.o \*.c

          If  there is no space between -x and the pattern, just one value
          is assumed (no list):

                 zip -r foo foo -x\*.o


          See -i for more on include and exclude.
```